# I am trying to deploy my fusioncharts chart on an actual web server

Tags: iis, asp-classic, vbscript, webserver

I am trying to deploy my fusioncharts chart on an actual web server. It is written in ASP and VB. Also I have been able to deploy the charts on IIS through my localhost. So does anyone know if you need to change something simple or anything like that? One last thing is that my HTML code on the asp file shows up but not one smidgen of ASP code is visible...... Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: You don't need to change anything for fusioncharts. I'm not sure what you are asking in your second question, or if it is a question at all. Why not just test these things?

Comment: Im trying to ask why does the asp page not display anything when I run it on our web server. Only the html title is viewable. I can run it on my local host and I see the chart and everything.... But when I switch it over i just get a blank area where the charts should be.. I guess my question is wtf does it not smoothly transition over. I figured if it worked on my localhost then it should work everywhere else

Comment: Download firebug for Firefox. It will help you debug these sorts of situations.

Comment: Wow that firebug add on is super useful when trying to really examine the html code! Thanks for the advice:)

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I just found out how to do it. First of all apparently asp code isn't visible when your trying to test it from the server. You have to go to the actual website to view the page..... I guess thats what you meant by testing Nathan....:P Thanks